# Http Post request with volley

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley, bad-request

i am using volley to request to the server i have this url that i post my DeviceId, manufacturer, android version etc and i got a aeskey and aesiv base64 encoded and a Authorization key so then to another url i sent this Authorization key as a header and as a body i need to put "period(it can be = 'all' , 'increasing', 'decreasing' etc )" which is encrypted by the aeskey and aesiv with aes256 with padding PKCS7 and ECB or CBC. But i get response from the first request but from the second request i got http 400 error i dont know what am i doing wrong. I dont have the access to server so to headers and to the parameters i am just adding what i am told to. I am thinking maybe i am doing the encryption wrong ?

this is how i decode base64 aeskey and aesiv

```
 key = response.getString("aesKey");
                    iv = response.getString("aesIV");
                    byte[] aeskey = Base64.decode(key, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    byte[] aesiv = Base64.decode(iv, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

this is my first request code

```
public void getData(String url,String deviceID) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject datas = new JSONObject();
        datas.put("deviceID", deviceID);
        datas.put("systemVersion", Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        datas.put("platformName","Android");
        datas.put("deviceModel",Build.MODEL);
        datas.put("manifacturer",Build.MANUFACTURER);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, datas, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                System.out.println(response);
                
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println(error.toString());
            }
        }){


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

                return params;
            }
        };



        queue.getCache().clear();
        queue.add(req);

    }
```

this is my encryption method

```
public static byte[] encrypt(String plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv) throws Exception
    {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");

        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, paramSpec);

        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
        return cipherText;
    }
```

this is my second method for second request

```
public void getanotherdata(String url, String period, final String auth) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject datas1 = new JSONObject();
        datas1.put("period", period);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, datas1, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                    System.out.println("burası çalıştı");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println(error.toString());
            }
        }){


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                params.put("X-VP-Authorization", auth);
                System.out.println("AUTH DEĞERİ "+ auth);

                return params;
            }
        };



        queue.getCache().clear();
        queue.add(req);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got 2 possible answers

1. You may be facing an encoding issue with the header itself, to be verified in RFC-2616 about HTTP standard, the header field-name has to be a token that is made out of 1 or more CHAR = <any US-ASCII character (octets 0 - 127)>
2. Maybe one of the proxy layer ( like nginx or similar ) is "eating" the header out of the requests before it gets to the server. Maybe you should verify on the receiving server that emits the 400 that it receives correclty the header that contains the authentication information.

Comment: so if the first one is my problem there is nothing i can do ? because i cant acces the server and if the second one is the problem how can i verify that the server gets the right data

Comment: If it is the Base64 result you hook in as a value for field-name X-VP-Authorization, it will compliant to us-ascii. Now, if the server on the other end can not read the header you are sending, that may be their problem to fix, or perhaps, they read it but can not validate it. Is there some api documentation to read against so we can see if you are computing the correct things ?

Comment: unfortunately i dont have any documentaion as well but i have found the solution, appereantly i had to send the encrypted "period" data with base64 encoded so after i do that i get the right response, you inspired me so many thanks.